# CGRectIntersectsRect problems, overlapping frames but not detecting it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to create an app for iPad and it's been fine so far, and now i am trying to make an object jump, so i've made it that it jumps up into the air and then falls down again, and thats working fine. but my problem comes when i want it to stop at the ground again, i thought CGRectIntersectsRect would work but it just doesn't work, i mean the object is clearly overlapping the ground image, but it's not stopping.

Code:

```
    -(void)gameStatePlayNormal{

    if(cubeState == CubeIsTouchingGround){
        cubeVelocity.y = 0;
    }

    gravity = CGPointMake(0, kGravity);

    cube.center = CGPointMake(cube.center.x, cube.center.y + cubeVelocity.y);
    cubeVelocity.y += gravity.y;

    if(touchState == Touch){

        if(cubeState != CubeIsJumping){
            cubeState = CubeIsJumping;
            cubeVelocity.y = cubeVelocity.y -10;
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(cubejump) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

        }

    }

}
-(void)cubejump{

    if(cubeState == CubeIsJumping){
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(cube.frame, ground.frame)){   
            NSLog(@"Cube is touching the ground.");
            cubeState = CubeIsTouchingGround;
            cubeVelocity.y = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

and the .h file:

```
    UIImageView *cube;
    UIImageView *spike;
    UIImageView *box;
    UIImageView *ground;

}

-(void)gameStatePlayNormal;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *cube;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *spike;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *box;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ground;
```

and of course everything is linked up in the .xib file, i can manipulate both the ground image and the cube image in other ways so those are linked to the variable in the xib file.

please help, i tried using the self.view.bounds.size.width as well but it didn't work for the lower part of the screen. please help :)

Comment: First thing to do would be to put `NSLog (@"Cube: %@\t\tGround: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cube.frame),NSStringFromCGRect(ground.frame));` into your `-(void)cubejump`. Run the animation and post the console output. We'll go from there on.

Comment: Cube: {{308, 512.46}, {70, 70}}  Ground: {{4.85517e-35, 4.85517e-35}, {3.16007e-41, 3.16007e-41}}

Comment: rechek the ground.frame settings - where do you set this? - this result you've posted probably isn't something one would expect